# Trying to create function that would compare my age to somebody else's age

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, compare

Trying to create a function that would compare my age to somebody else's age. Clearly, I'm missing something because no matter what input-output is always the same. Please help.

```
This is what I have so far:
function compareAge(name,age){
  let myAge=27;
  if (age = myAge){
    return `${name} is the same age as me.`
  }else if (age < myAge){
    return `${name} is younger than me.`
  }else if (age > myAge){
    return `${name} is older than me.`
  }
}
  console.log(compareAge('Kat',2));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this if Statement you are assigning `age` the value of `myAge` and passing the result to the if.

```
if (age = myAge){
```

In Javascript the boolean value of any integer is true.

```
console.log(Boolean(27));
//prints true
```

To actually compare the values `age` and `myAge`you need to use the double equal sign operator. Like this:

```
function compareAge(name,age){
  let myAge=27;
  if (age == myAge){
    return `${name} is the same age as me.`
  }else if (age < myAge){
    return `${name} is younger than me.`
  }else if (age > myAge){
    return `${name} is older than me.`
  }
}
  console.log(compareAge('Kat',2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes sense now why it wasn't working before.